# Can't make regex work with Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the date in format of: dd Month yyyy (20 August 2013).
I tried the following regex:

```
\d{2} (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4}
```

It works with regex testers (chcked with several the text - Monday, 19 August 2013), but It seems that Python doesn't understand it. The output I get is:

```
>>> 
['August']
>>>
```

Can somebody please understand me why is that happening ?

Thank you !

Comment: If @smerny answered your question, please hit the check-mark next to his answer to accept it.

Comment: I am interested to know the method in re you are using.

Comment: `import re
date = "20 August 2013"
print re.match("\d{2} (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4}", date).group()`

This seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use `re.findall`? By default, if there's at least one capture group in the pattern, `re.findall` will return only the captured parts of the expression.

You can avoid this by removing every capture group, causing `re.findall` to return the entire match:

```
\d{2} (?:January|February|...|December) \d{4}
```

or by making a single big capture group:

```
(\d{2} (?:January|February|...|December) \d{4})
```

or, possibly more conveniently, by making every component a capture group:

```
(\d{2}) (January|February|...|December) (\d{4})
```

This latter form is more useful if you will need to process the individual day/month/year components.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are only getting the data from the capture group, try this:

```
(\d{2} (?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{4})
```

I put a capture group around the entire thing and made the month a non-capture group. Now whatever was giving you "August" should give you the entire thing.

---

I just looked at some python regex stuff [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

```
>>> p = re.compile('(a(b)c)d')
>>> m = p.match('abcd')
>>> m.group(0)
'abcd'
>>> m.group(1)
'abc'
>>> m.group(2)
'b'
```

Seeing this, I'm guessing (since you didn't show how you were actually using this regex) that you were doing `group(1)` which will now work with the regex I supplied above.

It also looks like you could have used `group(0)` to get the whole thing (if I am correct in the assumption that this is what you were doing). This would work in your original regex as well as my modified version.

Comment: Thank you, that is working, but Can you explain a bit what was my mistake ?